# Filepath to a file on a RMI Server Java

Tags: java, xml, rmi

I have a simple project with a client and a server being connected via RMI. The server builds an xml file, transforms it and saves it as a html file. (currently all running on localhost)

Now the client should be able to access this particular file and display it in a browser, but I don't know how to access the correct file/file path.

**Server transforms xml to html and saves it**

```
    public void transform() throws RemoteException {
    TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Source xsldoc = new StreamSource("style.xsl");
    Source xmldoc = new StreamSource(getData().getFile());

    getData().setHmtlFile(new File("htmlconvert.html"));

    try {
        OutputStream htmlFile = new FileOutputStream(getData().getHmtlFile());

        Transformer tr = tFactory.newTransformer(xsldoc);
        tr.transform(xmldoc, new StreamResult(htmlFile));

    } catch (FileNotFoundException | TransformerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

**Client opens file in a browser**

```
public void openBrowser() {
    try {
        client.lookup.transform();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(client.lookup.getData().getHmtlFile());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**The exception being thrown**

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The file: htmlconvert.html doesn't exist.

Comment: It can't, unless the client and server are running in the same host, in which case you hardly need RMI at all. Are you looking for a Web server?

Comment: That's good to know.
Not at the moment, no. It's for an university project, so the localhost should be enough. The tasks is to tranform the xml to hmtl by the server and afterwards view it by the client.

Writing a transform method on client side seems to be way more logical (and actually works), but I wanted to stick to the the task.